# R function to check the multiple texts in a string

Tags: r, string, search

I am facing a problem in finding a solution in R

I have to find out the strings having 4 texts :

```
1. " { M/s ",
2. " { M/s. ",
3. " ( S/O - ",
4. " ( W/O - "
```

and put the output in if statement in R

```
dd<- data.frame(narr=c("Ratnakar:LIMITED::::CNAAJPIOP0::::Ratnakar:LIMITED",
                       "BAR-BOKALAWA:::Kl RAM I:: { M/s. REJOICE CONFECTIONARS ::BARBOKALAWA:::Kl RAM I",
                       "P2A:::REFUND::: { M/s AANCHAL SAREES :::1(NETPREM KUMAR SINGH)",
                       "P2A:: SUNDER ( S/O - JITENDER PAL ::REFUND:::::rajdhani:lawn",
                       "SAA::PRUD:::P2A::::SAA::PRUD",
                       "SAA-NOON:MOO: RAJNI ( W/O - RAM NIVAS::P2A::REFUND::SAA:NOON:MOO",
                       "CMS.CAR:::SAA:::CMS::CAR"))

This is running fine : str_detect(dd$narr, " M/s | M/s.| W/O | C/O | S/O ")


But, This is not running : str_detect(dd$narr, " { M/s | { M/s.| ( W/O | ( C/O | ( S/O ")
```

> Error is coming :
> Error in stri_detect_regex(string, pattern, negate = negate, opts_regex = opts(pattern)) :
> Error in {min,max} interval. (U_REGEX_BAD_INTERVAL)
> Please help me out.

Comment: Try: `stringr::str_detect(dd$narr, " \\{ M/s | \\{ M/s\\.| \\( W/O | \\( C/O | \\( S/O ")`

Comment: Yes, Done, I was almost there. Thanks for replying.

Answer (score 2):

```
str_detect(dd$narr, " \\{ M/s | \\{ M/s\\.| \\( W/O | \\( C/O | \\( S/O ")
```

Answer (score 2):

`?regexp` says: *Any metacharacter with special meaning may be quoted by preceding it with a backslash.*

```
stringr::str_detect(dd$narr, " \\{ M/s | \\{ M/s\\.| \\( W/O | \\( C/O | \\( S/O ")
#[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```